# Update JSON values from excel sheet

Tags: java, json, excel

So I am facing tricky problem.
I have a JSON file in below format

```
 {
    "mainParent":
    {
"parentA":
[ {
"node1": nodevalue1,
"node2": nodevalue2,
"node3": nodevalue3,
},
{
"node2": nodevalue5,
"node3": nodevalue6,
},
{
"node1": nodevalue1,
"node3": nodevalue3,
}

]
                  }
```

Corresponding to this JSON ,I have one excel workbook,that will store JSON data in the following format.
[image]

As you can see,
 `parentA[0]` contains 3 nodes :`node1,node2,node3`.
`parentA[1]` contains: `node2,node3` 
`parentA[2]` contains: `node1,node3` 
My JSON can have any node from `node1 to node3` , and also can skip any node(s)
I have to update JSON values from excel.
The problem is excel will have all the nodes, even the ones that are not present in the excel

How can I proceed
Please help.

Comment: you update the JSON from excel using java?

Comment: @GowthamShiva : Yes , my requirement is like that only .